# Ontology population tool that works with linguistically tagged data - similar to OntoTL but supported?

Tags: knowledge-organization, knowledge-base

I am looking for an ontology population tool that I would be able to use to map linguistically tagged corpora onto an existing ontology.

I found OntoTL but the last version of Protege it works with is the 3. series, so I just thought I would see on here if there are any other suggestions that might still be supported.

I am looking for this for a project which aims to use corpus analysis to discover relationships between species in the literature. I am hoping to be able to use an ontology to display the results of this.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking a look at the [Python](https://www.python.org/) Natural Language Tool Kit, ([nltk](http://www.nltk.org/)) to see how simple it might be to "roll your own".

Comment: Thank you Steve. I am looking at the NLTK, so I will bear that in mind.